# identifying what has changed in the data year on year

Tags: classification, pca, meta-analysis, correspondence-analysis

I have a dataset from one year and the 'same' dataset for the next year. I would like to identify what has changed in the datasets between the years. Both datasets have the same columns.

I currently use/explore 2 approaches.

(1) Use a classification decision tree to predict the depended variable year as factor. The idea is that the tree tells me what are the discriminating factors between the years. This appears to highlight some columns.

(2) Use factor analysis of mixed data (FAMD) (I use the R packages FactoMineR + factor extra). This reveals high quality columns (measured by cos2) and high contribution columns (measured by contrib).

Are these valid approaches? Could anyone please suggest another approach?

I have to say that I am currently a bit confused about the interpretation of quality versus contribution for approach 2. Could someone please be so kind and explain this a bit better? Which measure is better for my problem?

Comment: How are your independent and your dependent variables scaled?

Comment: do you mean for the decision tree? How do you scale independent factors for FAMD?

Comment: btw I scale numeric columns in R using scale()

Comment: Predicting year using binary logistic regression is an excellent approach to such detective work.  But why do you think that something changed exactly on January 1?  If the changes are smooth you could use regular regression to predict the number of days from the first date in the dataset.

Comment: Thanks Frank. This sounds interesting. Could you please elaborate? If assumptions of LR are violated (and/or if I do not consider interactions) I may jump to wrong conclusions. How would you models change of data set composition over time anyway? Please note that some factors are very granular as well ... Thanks.

Comment: @FrankHarrell makes an excellent point. Are years really discrete? If years means e.g. separate summers or more generally replicates that are distinct, then year could be a useful covariate, but unless calendar changes have intrinsic meaning, its merit is less obvious. Also, how is variability within years being handled if you have a process in time?

Comment: Ok I get your point. But how do I detect that there is some change over time for a variable without having to look at (too) many time series manually.. Making something up: number of female employees over time.

Comment: Should this be more a change point detection problem?

Comment: You don't need to look at many times manually.  If changes over time are monotonic you can use ordinary regression to predict the mean number of days from the first day.  To detect an up-and-down relationship on the other hand you can either use canonical variates (to predict say days and days squared) or assume that the peak/nadir was at some middle time point and predict the absolute number of days from that point, using regression.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit dim. Can you please elude how prediction of the mean number of days is relevant in this context?

Comment: If a variable changes over time, time predicts that variable.  If time predicts a variable, the variable predicts time.  This is a trick to turn a model upside down so you can simultaneously look at multiple variables being related to time.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please be so kind and compose an answer? Or is this approach about right? Let us say we have one continuous variable (age) and a factor (gender). Every sample also has a date entry. I can calculate days given min(date) for each sample. Should I then aggregate the other variables (e.g. median age, number of males, number of females) over time to predict time/days? Could use a random forest and feature importance to detect changing variables. What do you think?

Comment: Don't do any aggregation.  Use only raw data to estimate the simultaneous relationships between all the variables and continuous time in days.  Ordinary regression comes to mind.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try. Obviously, if ols regression's assumptions are violated I cannot jump to any conclusions. Using a machine learning model (e.g. regression tree) may be better as it takes automatically care of interactions and has hardly any assumptions? Please add answer?